# Sort order of files

Tags: c#, vb.net, file, sorting, getfiles

Good morning together,

I have this files:

file1_mytext.xml

file1a_mytext.xml

file1b_mytext.xml

(this is how the windows explorer shows the order)

with

```
... FileSystem.Getfiles(path)
```

or

```
... Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
```

I get an order like this:

file1a_mytext.xml

file1b_mytext.xml

file1_mytext.xml

How do I get the top order?

Thanks for your help

Comment: [Related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Same principle as the question linked to above but [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?887616)'s one I prepared earlier.

Comment: Seems like plenty of different approaches to choose from in the duplicate. What have you tried? What _specifically_ do you need help with?